# How to position actionbar navigation dropdown menu above second fragment in master detail layout

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I have master detail layout in my app (see picture on the left):
[image]

I have navigation mode list set for actionbar (using it for filtering listview in second fragment):

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

I removed my activity title from actionbar with:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The problem is that my drop down menu now appears above the first fragment (on the left side of the actionbar), as if it is refering to first fragment. This might confuse the user.

How can i place actionbar dropdown menu above second fragment?

Answer (score 0):

there's no direct API to do what you want (move the spinner to the middle of the ActionBar)

Your best option to achieve something remotely similar to that is to create your own view with a spinner and user the [setCustomView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) method from the actionbar.